# MVC consistency, present a viewController from the model

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a viewController I've built in storyboard. I also have a NSObject Subclass which acts as my model, which sends and listens for API requests and responses. When a method fires in my model, I want to present a modal View of my viewController from whatever view happens to be visible at the time.

An example would be if my API hears "show this view" I want to show viewController regardless of what view is being shown.

Conceptually, how does one do this?

EDIT: I don't know which view controller will be showing when I want to present my modal viewController. Also, I need to pass params from my model to the modalVC when it's presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would send a notification from the model telling "someone" that some view needs be displayed.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"TheViewKey": viewToDisplay];
[[NSNoticationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationThatThisViewNeedsToBeDisplayed" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

And then on the delegate (or the active view controller) would register to this notification and handle the display.

```
// self is the delegate and/or the view controller that will receive the notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleViewToDisplay:) name:@"NotificationThatThisViewNeedsToBeDisplayed" object:nil];
```

If you put in the view controller remember to remove self from the observers when the view is not visible:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"NotificationThatThisViewNeedsToBeDisplayed"];
```

This way your model is decoupled from the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have the current viewController (any viewController subclass) present the new view using:

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

EDIT: To find the top view controller, you ask the UITabBarController for the selectedViewController (if you use a tabBarController) to get the 'seed', or start with the window.rootViewController.

Once you are past any tabBarControllers, then you should only have UIViewController subclasses and UINavigationControllers. You can use a loop like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)frontmostController:(UIViewController *)seed
{
    UIViewController *ret;
    if([seed isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        ret = [(UINavigationController *)seed topViewController];
    } else
    if([seed isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
        ret = seed.presentedViewController;
    }
    return ret ? [self frontmostController:ret] : seed;
}
```

Comment: how do I know which ViewController is currently up to call presentViewController from?

Comment: I see you awarded the answer to the notification solution - that will work as long as the top view controller is one of your objects. The above solution will work even if the top object is some apple class like the email message class. Also, be aware that the logic gets a little tricky when say a presented view controller resigns - every one of your view controllers has to have the proper logic in it to know to register back for the notification. Really, that solution is no different than using a global UIViewController and have your various classes set it to 'self' when they become frontmost.

Comment: can you explain the last line: return ret ? [self frontmostController:ret] : seed; I don't understand the language of that.

Comment: I don't think the notification invalidates this frontmostController: method. The notification just tells when to call the method and handle the display of the new view. Also, I agree with David you shouldn't put the notification in all your controllers, choose wisely which one will be the responsible. And for me the most important thing is to separate the model from this view logic.

Comment: The problem is always insuring in each class that the class recognizes when its become frontmost - this is not always obvious or straightforward [ask me how I know this :-) ]